# How to set time for a div with opacity?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can hover `product-list-item` div then the `add-to-cart` will appear. When I move the mouse out of `product-list-item`, it will disappear. How to set the appear's time of add-to-cart when the mouse is already on `product-list-item`?

```css
.product-list-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  height: 320px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(228, 225, 225);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.product-list-item:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 5px rgb(231, 231, 231);
}

.product-list-item:hover .add-to-cart {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 20px;
}

.add-to-cart {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.add-to-cart>.btn {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-list-item">
  <div class="add-to-cart">
    <button class="btn">add-to-cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a codepen:

https://codepen.io/quantranbber/pen/WNbezQb

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `transition-delay` when to `add-to-cart` when `product-list-item` is on hover to "set the [item's appearance delay]".

```css
.product-list-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  height: 320px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(228, 225, 225);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.product-list-item:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 5px rgb(231, 231, 231);
}

.product-list-item:hover .add-to-cart {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 20px;
  transition-delay: 3s; // Add the amount of time you want to delay
}

.add-to-cart {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.add-to-cart>.btn {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-list-item">
  <div class="add-to-cart">
    <button class="btn">add-to-cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```